# mb_ereg_search_regs different behaviour with b option switching from php 7.4.7 to php 7.4.8

Tags: php, regex, php-7.4, mbstring

I have code like this:

```php
$sTestString = "BEGIN:VEVENT";
$sPattern = '^(BEGIN|END)\:(.+)$';
$sRegex_opt = 'mib';
mb_ereg_search_init( $sTestString );
print_r(mb_ereg_search_regs( $sPattern, $sRegex_opt ));
```

With PHP 7.4.7 I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => BEGIN:VEVENT
    [1] => BEGIN
    [2] => VEVENT
)
```

With PHP >= 7.4.8 I get an empty return value.

It seems to be tied to the "b" option. When i remove the "b" option i get the same result for all versions.

Can anybody explain what i am missing and why the behaviour changed?

I also looked into the mbstring git code and found the following change, could that be related?

https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/3f2f36d5d4c5c3c77703b366a5c7f9c3682727ee#diff-32e1239f9793b36003223e8568e0deeb803c42839195f48817b9f8deaf32a0b1

Comment: Interesting, the `b` sets the flavor to ONIG_SYNTAX_POSIX_BASIC, and your regex won't work in POSIX BRE the way you want. So, it seems there used to be a bug that is now fixed.

Comment: I now read a bit about BRE (the code was written by a colleague some time ago). And i read everywhere that with BRE you would have to escape the Pipe and or the capturing group parentheses. But with `$sPattern = '^\(BEGIN\|END\)\:(.+)$';`  or `$sPattern = '^(BEGIN\|END)\:(.+)$';` i don't get a result with any PHP version. Could you tell me what is wrong about the regex? Or should i just drop the b option?

Comment: That just proves the `b` option is buggy. Remove it altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `b` option used with [`mb_regex_set_options`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-regex-set-options.php) is meant to enable you to use the "POSIX Basic" regex flavor.

You do not actually have to parse the `^(BEGIN|END)\:(.+)$` pattern with POSIX flavor, it is good enough to use the default.

Note that you do not need to escape the `:` char, it is not special, and you do not need the `$` since `.+` matches one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible (so, all till the end of the line).